# In a sequence of distinct numbers of length $n$ there is a monotonic subsequence of length at least $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that in any sequence of distinct numbers of length $n$ there is a monotonic subsequence of length at least $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$.

I thought, that induction would probably be best here.

So $n=1$ and $n=2$ are trivial.

Now let's assume all is well for $k \leq n$ and consider $n+1$. If from the first $n$ elements we can create a decreasing/increasing sequence and the last elements is smaller/bigger than all of them then this is trivial. We can also do the same analysis with the first element.

But what about other cases? I have literally now idea how to approach them.

Comment: Why "random"? Do you just mean any given sequence of $n$ numbers?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What if the numbers just happen to be (1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)?

Comment: Sorry again, added the requirement for the numbers to be distinct.

Comment: Oh, I guess you don't mean in the order given. So you could rearrange my numbers as 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 . I see.

Comment: No, I mean that. The desired monotonic sequence is a subsequence of a given sequence.

Comment: Are they necessarily integers?

Comment: Yes. They are integers.

Comment: Induction on $n$ may not be as promising as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the theorem of Erdos and Szekeres. There are about a half dozen proofs in the paper http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Papers/PDF/VOTMSTOEAS.pdf